# Using dimension formula to prove subspace dimension formula

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I've always suspected the formulas $\dim F+G = \dim F + \dim G - \dim F\cap G$ and $\dim V = \dim  \mathrm{Ker} T + \dim \mathrm{Im} T$ were related someway. So I tried proving the former using the latter.

It is easy to see that the direct outer product $F\times G$ has dimension the sum of dimensions of $F$ and $G$. Define $\pi: F\times G \twoheadrightarrow F+G$ by $\pi(f,g) = f+g$. It is clearly surjective. I claim that the kernel of $\pi$ is the subspace $H$ of $(F\cap G)^2$ of elements of form $(f, -f)$, and therefore of dimension equal to the one of $F\cap G$. Therefore the former result results from applying the dimension formula to $\pi$.

Is this correct?

Comment: It is correct. Perhaps it's more illuminating if you define $\pi$ as $\pi(f,g)=f-g$.